# How to get part of a string that doesn't contain last 2 words separate by an underscore

Tags: python-3.x

I have various table names that always fit this format:

```
au_mba_lms_prod
au_mba_social_prod
au_mba_ch_prod
au_mba_cmt_prod
texas_tech_mba_lms_prod
texas_tech_mba_social_prod
four_word_school_name_lms_prod
```

In Python3, if I want to get rid of the `_lms_prod` at the end, and keep `au_mba` and `four_word_school_name`, how can I go about doing this? What regex can I use? What python method can I use?

Answer (score 0):

this will do it if you put all of them into an array.

```
array = ['au_mba_lms_prod', 'au_mba_social_prod', 'au_mba_ch_prod', 'au_mba_cmt_prod', 'texas_tech_mba_lms_prod', 'texas_tech_mba_social_prod', 'four_word_school_name_lms_prod']

for item in array:
    if '_lms_prod' in item:
        r = item.replace('_lms_prod', '')
        array.remove(item)
        array.insert(0, r)
    else:
        pass

print(array)
# output will be: ['four_word_school_name', 'texas_tech_mba', 'au_mba', 'au_mba_social_prod', 'au_mba_ch_prod', 'au_mba_cmt_prod', 'texas_tech_mba_social_prod']
```